# How to call object from other class to another class and add it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new for android java coding. I'm try to do menu list where just have tick box, and once tick the items, n press next, it should go to view layout and show items and the total of the item selected, then press next it should open details page where user must put their details n press send button to send via email.  I don't know how to call the items from menu to Cart and to confirmation class.

This is menu.java .

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
 
 Button btnorder; 
 Button btnback;
 Button btnlinkcart;
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        
  btnlinkcart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btnback  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  
   // back button click event
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    
   }
        });
        
     // Link to Cart Screen
       btnlinkcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
           ViewActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
         finish();
        }
       });
 }

}
```

This is Cart.java

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
 
 Button btnconfirm;
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.cart);
        
  btnconfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  
  // Link to Cart Screen
   btnconfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
       ConfirmActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
    }
   });
 }

}
```

This is cart.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" >

   
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is menu.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Large) RM30.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Mediume) RM20.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Personal) RM10.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Chicken Wings RM12.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Garlic Bread RM6.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Soft Drink (Large) RM5.00" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Soft Drink (Medium) RM4.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you want to do and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable you want to get in the menu class static, then in the cart class you can get them like this:

menu.variableFromMenuClass

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static ArrayList<YourObject>  selectItemList= new ArrayList<YourObject>();


 on selectItem(){
 //each Item you add here 
 selectedList.add(selectedObject);
 }

 on disselectItem(){
//remove if exist in list
 selectedList.remove(disselectedOject);
 }


sendemail(){
 send your public static selecteditem list.

}
```

**This is the algorithm you have to write simple.**

Comment: This answer makes no sense. But the method names containing a space that will not even compile is probably my favorite part. I've seen it all.

Comment: From the help page : "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: don't be personnel to someone.
it's against the humanity.
So, i think you first need this lesson then development.
God bless you and hope show you right path.

Comment: Nothing personal, I just found most of your answers to be sloppy and/or completely incorrect, and the advised behavior on this site is to vote that down, so people trying to learn will not get distracted by false information. Now, providing guess-based answers just to gain some reputation on this website, that really goes against trying to help others, which is arguably worse to the humanity. Don't worry about my learning of development, worry about yours, it really needs some work, your code would not pass any code review of mine.

Comment: sometimes you don't have time to answer completely you just give the way to think.

Comment: i never say i am champion in development.

Comment: "sometimes you don't have time to answer completely you just give the way to think" => then use comments. And pointing people in the right direction only works if the information you give is correct. Which is not the case here.

Comment: you have only this thing to do.

Comment: we have much more important task to do rather than creating repo.
and one i start creating repo no one can stop me.
if you don't like or not want to accept the answer just vote down.
simple!!!!

Comment: Not less than you, obviously, and I have a lot of free time when Im attending meetings :) Go learn now, or better yet delete all those bad answers of yours, and then go study.